# twilio multiple simultaneous conversations per user

Tags: twilio

Here's an example:

Every time a user sells a car, he has to reply to my system to say what the color of the car is that he sold (my system knows that a car was sold and what its make is but not what color it was).

If the user sells only 1 car at a time and texts back immediately, I can remember which car he is talking about by storing information about the current_car in a session variable. If, on the other hand, the user sells 3 cars simultaneously, I can't store a current_car session variable because there are 3 current cars.

How do I know which car the user is talking about when he replies to my text? Is there any way to embed a unique token in the text message I send so that the reply references the correct car out of the 3 cars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Twilio API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api) doesn't support that. Have you noticed what Twitter does for the same precise use-case?  They include in the original SMS instructions such as "reply directly with ....".  The user would have to type that in so keep it simple.

Alternatively, *you* can reply to the ambiguous messages with "There were three cars. Which sold? (reply with number 1, 2, or 3)"

Comment: The Twilio API doesn't support it correct. We would however if it were possible but the global SMS system only passes the sender's phone number, the recipient's phone number and the body of the message so there's no way for us to know which message is being replied to.

Comment: @John: that's what I actually assumed as well.  But wasn't sure that is fact and was too lazy to google it ;) No intent to indicate this was a shortcoming of Twillo.

Comment: Thanks guys. So basically I can do the following: 1) If I have one open conversation for a pair of numbers (my twilio number and a user), I can assume I know what the user is referring to when he replies. 2) If there are more than one open conversations, I can create a menu system like you suggest. 3) Since a conversation is number-specific, as long as I only have one open conversation per number then I could assume I know what the user is talking about when he replies w/o a menu system. Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: Its a reasonable workaround.  Note that the hack of sending selection list for ambiguous responses won't scale; the 'menu' must fit in the limited sms payload size. The alt. is less user friendly but it will work regardless of # of conversations.